# Display a message at the end of a Rails Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, templates, bundler

I'm using Rails 3.2.1 and have created my own rails template. I want to display a set of instructions after the initial install, but bundler seems to run and pushes my messages up the screen.

Is there a way to stop bundler running after my template? 
Or better still is there a way to display a message after bundler has run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a dirty hack, but you can disable the built-in 'bundle install' invocation by overriding the `run_bundle` method:

```
def run_bundle ; end
```

If you still want your template to run `bundle install`, you can invoke this using the `run` command:

```
run "bundle install"
```

Alternatively, just use this line in your template:

```
run_bundle ; def run_bundle ; end
```

HTH.